# Change billing address fields type woocommercce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the type of some fields in my account page, where i want to change City from "textfield" to `<select>` (list) where I specify only some cities, I don't want users to type anything, do you have any idea on which code shall I edit?
I tried with this but I don't know what to modifie!

I want only three cities to be selected (Paris, London, Algiers)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields' );

    function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields ) {

       $fields['billing_city']  = array(
          'label'          => __('City', 'woothemes'),
          'placeholder'    => __('City', 'woothemes'),
          'required'       => true,
          'class'          => array('billing-city')
       );

     return $fields;
    }
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try below code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields' );

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields ) {

   $fields['billing_city']  = array(
      'type'            => 'select',
      'label'          => __('City', 'woothemes'),
      'placeholder'    => __('City', 'woothemes'),
      'required'       => true,
      'class'          => array('billing-city'),
      'options'     => array(
            'paris' => __('Paris', 'woothemes' ),
            'london' => __('London', 'woothemes' ),
            'algiers' => __('Algiers', 'woothemes' )
        )
   );

 return $fields;
}
```

Comment: It works man thanks, you only need to add a comma at the end of this line : 'london' => __('London', 'woothemes' )

Comment: Woocommerce ask me to insert shipping address for chckout even it is already set!!!! do you have any idea?

Comment: I think you have forget to fill out any field. Could you please check all those fields are correct?

Comment: I disabled shipping address and I let billing address us it was by default but it still the same! it doesn't recognize that the billing address is set!